# including a loop for the function so it can ask the user to re enter a number if the number is incorrect

Tags: python, python-3.8

I need to modify my program so it includes a prime read with a loop. the document is saying for my getNumber function it should ask the user only to input a number between 2 and 30, the getScores function should ask the user to input a number between 0 and 100. it they don't get a number between that it should tell them re enter a number. I don't get any errors when running the program but not sure what I am missing in order to make sure its running properly to include the re enter a number part. here is the code:

```
# main
def main():
    endProgram = 'no'
    print
    while endProgram == 'no':
        totalScores = 0
        averageScores = 0
        number = 0
        number = getNumber(number)
        totalScores = getScores(totalScores, number)
        averageScores = getAverage(totalScores, averageScores, number)
        printAverage(averageScores)
        endProgram = input('Do you want to end the program? yes or no ')
        while not (endProgram != 'yes' or endProgram != 'no'):
            print('Enter yes or no ')
            endProgram = input('Do you want to end the program? (yes or no )')

# this function will determine how many students took the test
def getNumber(number):
    number = int(input('How many students took the test: '))
    return number
    while number < 2 or number > 30:
        print('Please enter a number between 2 and 30')
        number = int(input('How many students took the test: '))

# this function will get the total scores
def getScores(totalScores, number):
    for counter in range(0, number):
        score = int(input('Enter their score: '))
    return totalScores
    while score < 0 or score > 100:
            print('Please enter a number between 0 and 100')
            score = int(input('Enter their score: '))
            return score

# this function will calculate the average
def getAverage(totalScores, averageScores, number):
    averageScores = totalScores / number
    return averageScores

# this function will display the average
def printAverage(averageScores):
    print ('The average test score is: ', averageScores)  

# calls main
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion is to change this:

```
number = int(input('How many students took the test: '))
```

reason is that, as it is written, this takes the user input and implicitly assumes that it can be cast to an `int`. What happens if the user enters "*hello, world!*" as input? It is necessary to take the user input first as a string, and check if it would be valid to convert it:

```
number = input("enter a number:")
if number.isdecimal():
    number = int(number)
```

Next, the function as a whole has some structural problems:

```
def getNumber(number):
    number = int(input('How many students took the test: '))
    return number
    while number < 2 or number > 30:
        print('Please enter a number between 2 and 30')
        number = int(input('How many students took the test: '))
```

number is passed in as an argument to `getNumber`. Then the name `number` is reassigned to the result of reading the user input, and returned... Make sure you understand what the `return` statement does: once the control flow reaches a return statement, that function terminates, and it sends that value back to the caller. So your `while` loop never runs.

Maybe this would work better:

```
def getNumber():
    while number := input("enter a number"):
        if number.isdecimal() and int(number) in range(0, 31):
            return int(number)
        print('Please enter a number between 2 and 30')
```